# autocomplete in OSX terminal after `npm run tdd` command

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I'm using OSX 10.10.3, i have installed `zsh`. And every time when i want to run a specific test i configured in package.json to execute `npm run tdd` followed by the test file.

In linux systems if i press `tab` after this command:

`npm run tdd ~/`

will show me the folders or will attempt to autocomplete the instruction, however this doesn't happen in the OSX terminal, it just makes the noise like there are no recommendations for this.

How can this be fixed?, :)

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you installed `oh-my-zsh`? It has a `npm` plugin and also it is extensible.